# Error while Recompilng apk with apktool

Tags: apktool

I can't recompile any apk with apktool, here is the error log:

```
W: Could not find sources
invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\pradeepkumar\Downloads\Compressed\Advanced+ApkTool+v4.1.0+By+BDFreak\AdvancedApkTool\3-Out\framework-res.apk\res values-?@-rES
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [C:\Users\PRADEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_5055861152156375473.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 1, --min-sdk-version, 21, --target-sdk-version, 21, --version-code, 21, --version-name, 5.0.2-d3aebb81ea, -F, C:\Users\PRADEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL1542257552202253955.tmp, -x, -0, arsc, -S, C:\Users\pradeepkumar\Downloads\Compressed\Advanced+ApkTool+v4.1.0+By+BDFreak\AdvancedApkTool\3-Out\framework-res.apk\res, -M, C:\Users\pradeepkumar\Downloads\Compressed\Advanced+ApkTool+v4.1.0+By+BDFreak\AdvancedApkTool\3-Out\framework-res.apk\AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:437)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:374)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:277)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:250)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:225)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [C:\Users\PRADEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_5055861152156375473.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 1, --min-sdk-version, 21, --target-sdk-version, 21, --version-code, 21, --version-name, 5.0.2-d3aebb81ea, -F, C:\Users\PRADEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL1542257552202253955.tmp, -x, -0, arsc, -S, C:\Users\pradeepkumar\Downloads\Compressed\Advanced+ApkTool+v4.1.0+By+BDFreak\AdvancedApkTool\3-Out\framework-res.apk\res, -M, C:\Users\pradeepkumar\Downloads\Compressed\Advanced+ApkTool+v4.1.0+By+BDFreak\AdvancedApkTool\3-Out\framework-res.apk\AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:488)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:423)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [C:\Users\PRADEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_5055861152156375473.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 1, --min-sdk-version, 21, --target-sdk-version, 21, --version-code, 21, --version-name, 5.0.2-d3aebb81ea, -F, C:\Users\PRADEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL1542257552202253955.tmp, -x, -0, arsc, -S, C:\Users\pradeepkumar\Downloads\Compressed\Advanced+ApkTool+v4.1.0+By+BDFreak\AdvancedApkTool\3-Out\framework-res.apk\res, -M, C:\Users\pradeepkumar\Downloads\Compressed\Advanced+ApkTool+v4.1.0+By+BDFreak\AdvancedApkTool\3-Out\framework-res.apk\AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:89)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:482)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Did you tried running latest version of apktool?

Answer (score 0):

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/pull/100) in the latest apktool code base, `RC4` does not have this fix. I [blogged](http://connortumbleson.com/2015/04/10/apktool-fixing-bug-761/) about fixing this bug a few days ago. So [build](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/build/) from source or wait for the final release of Apktool.

Basically the `BCP-47` qualifier and 3 characters packed into 2 bytes is not supported with the version you have. Thus `ast-rES` is decoded improperly, which creates the invalid directory error.